# Как достать нужную инфу из списка json'ов который на самом деле строка?

Tags: python, json, строки, dataframe

У меня есть `dataframe` с полем типа `string`, которое выглядит как список json'ов (может содержать от 1-го до 9 элементов json всегда одного формата `id1, id2, date`).

пример: `[{'id1': 'A', 'id2': 'B', 'date': '2021-08-01'}, {'id2': 'B', 'date': '2021-08-02', 'id1': 'A'}]`.

Нужно обработать случаи, когда в списке два элемента.
Для каждого элемента df сравнить id1 в первом элементе списка с id2 во втором, например. Как можно это адекватно сделать? Мб можно сделать из этой строки настоящий список json'ов? Попытаться достать какими-нибудь регулярками(но здесь лично у меня возникают проблемы из-за присутсивя символов одинарных ковычек + на большом датафрейме кажется не быстрым)?

UPD:
сам df достаточно большой и с очень большим количеством столбцов,
основные это date, type, op_id, status, desc итд
поле desc - то с которым нужно работать.
Можно и в отдельный распарсить, если подскажете как, но главное чтобы была тогда возможность информацию, полученную из каждой строки нового датафрейма, смэтчить обратно с df по op_id :)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'op_id':'1', 'desc':"[{'id1': 'A', 'id2': 'B', 'date': '2021-08-01'}, {'id2': 'B', 'date': '2021-08-02', 'id1': 'A'}]"}, 
{'op_id':'2', 'desc':"[{'id1': 'C', 'id2': 'D', 'date': '2021-08-02'}]'"}, 
{'op_id':'3', 'desc':"[{'id1': 'A', 'id2': 'D', 'date': '2021-07-02'}]"}])
```

Comment: а можно пример всего датафрейма в студию? может, там проще это поле распарсить в отдельный датафрейм и с ним векторно работать?

Comment: @strawdog указала)